# Method Override with Scala 3 Macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm trying to override a method with use of Scala 3 macros and TASTY. I'd like to override any method of any type. Now I'm starting with this simple case.

I have a test base class:

```
class TestClass {
  def func(s: String) = "base"
}
```

I'd like to achieve this, but with use of TASTY as I found out that it is impossible to call `new A` on a generic type with quotes and splices:

```
'{
    new TestClass() {
       override def func(s: String) = "override"
    }
}.asExprOf[A]
```

I printed AST of the above code and I managed almost to recreate it. The problem is that I cannot call `new` on the generated class - I don't see a way to access the symbol or type of the new class. I also tried `Symbol.requiredClass()` with the new name, though it returned some symbol, I got an error during macro expansion that the class isn't found.

My questions are:

- Is it possible at all to derive custom types without explicitly invoking: `new Class {}` in quotes?
- Does `ClassDef.copy` register a new name that can assist with new instance creation?
- Can manual invocations of `ClassDef` create an instance of the class?
- How can I make use of a symbol returned by `Symbol.requiredClass` as it returns something even if not defined before?

The code that I created:

```
import scala.quoted.*

object NewClass {

  def newClassImpl[A: Type](e: Expr[A])(using Quotes): Expr[A] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*

    val typeRep = TypeRepr.of[A]

    val ret = typeRep.classSymbol.map(_.tree) match {
      case Some(
            cd @ ClassDef(
              name: String,
              constr: DefDef,
              parents: List[Tree],
              selfOpt: Option[ValDef],
              body: List[Statement]
            )
          ) =>
        println(cd.show(using Printer.TreeAnsiCode))

        val newItemsOwner = Symbol.spliceOwner.owner
        println("newItemsOwner = " + newItemsOwner)

        def createFunction(args: Term)(using Quotes): Term = {
          args
        }

        val newConstrSymbol = Symbol.newMethod(
          newItemsOwner,
          "<init>",
          MethodType(Nil)(
            _ => Nil,
            _ => TypeRepr.of[Unit]
          ),
          Flags.EmptyFlags,
          Symbol.noSymbol
        )

        val newConstrDef: DefDef = DefDef(
          newConstrSymbol,
          {
            case List(List(paramTerm: Term)) =>
              Some(createFunction(paramTerm).changeOwner(newConstrSymbol))
            case _ => None
          }
        )

        val newMethodSymbol = Symbol.newMethod(
          newItemsOwner,
          "func",
          MethodType(List("s"))(
            _ => List(TypeRepr.of[String]),
            _ => TypeRepr.of[String]
          ),
          Flags.Override,
          Symbol.noSymbol
        )

        val newMethodDef: DefDef = DefDef(
          newMethodSymbol,
          {
            case List(List(paramTerm: Term)) =>
              Some(createFunction(paramTerm).changeOwner(newMethodSymbol))
            case _ => None
          }
        )

        val parentSel = Select.unique(New(TypeTree.of[A]), "<init>")
        val parent = Apply(parentSel, Nil)

        val newClassDef: ClassDef = ClassDef.copy(cd)(
          name + "$gen",
          newConstrDef,
          parent :: Nil,
          None,
          newMethodDef :: Nil
        )

        val app = Apply(
          Select(New(TypeIdent(Symbol.requiredClass(name + "$gen"))), newConstrDef.symbol),
          Nil
        )
      
        val block = Block(newClassDef :: Nil, Typed(app, TypeTree.of[A]))
        val finalTerm = Inlined(Some(TypeTree.of[NewClass$]), Nil, block)

        println(finalTerm.show(using Printer.TreeAnsiCode))
        println(finalTerm.show(using Printer.TreeStructure))

        finalTerm.asExprOf[A]


      case other =>
        println("No class def found: " + other)
        e
    }

    println("Returned:")
    println(ret.asTerm.show(using Printer.TreeAnsiCode))
    println(ret.asTerm.show(using Printer.TreeStructure))

    ret
  }

  inline def newClass[A](a: A): A = ${ newClassImpl[A]('{ a }) }
}
```

The returned code is printed without complains as:

```
{
@scala.annotation.internal.SourceFile("src/main/scala/MethodsMain.scala") class TestClass$gen() extends TestClass {
    override def func(s: java.lang.String): java.lang.String = s
  }

  (new TestClass$gen(): TestClass)
}
```

But if returned by the macro I got an error during expansion:

```
[error]   |Bad symbolic reference. A signature
[error]   |refers to TestClass$gen/T in package <empty> which is not available.
[error]   |It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error]   |the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling the signature.
[error]   | This location contains code that was inlined from NewClass.scala:86
```

Usage:

```
val res:TestClass = NewClass.newClass[TestClass](new TestClass)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

With new method `Symbol.newClass` (Scala 3.1.3) this becomes quite easy:

```scala
import scala.annotation.experimental
import scala.quoted.*

object NewClass {
  inline def newClass[A]: A = ${newClassImpl[A]}

  @experimental
  def newClassImpl[A: Type](using Quotes): Expr[A] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*

    val name: String = TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol.name + "Impl"
    val parents = List(TypeTree.of[A])

    def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
      List(Symbol.newMethod(cls, "func", MethodType(List("s"))(_ => List(TypeRepr.of[String]), _ => TypeRepr.of[String]), Flags.Override, Symbol.noSymbol))

    val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner, name, parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
    val funcSym = cls.declaredMethod("func").head

    val funcDef = DefDef(funcSym, argss => Some('{"override"}.asTerm))
    val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(funcDef))
    val newCls = Typed(Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent(cls)), cls.primaryConstructor), Nil), TypeTree.of[A])

    Block(List(clsDef), newCls).asExprOf[A]
  }
}
```

Usage:

```scala
class TestClass {
  def func(s: String) = "base"
}

val res: TestClass = NewClass.newClass[TestClass]

//{
//  class TestClassImpl extends TestClass {
//    override def func(s: java.lang.String): java.lang.String = "override"
//  }
//
//  (new TestClassImpl(): TestClass)
//}

res.func("xxx") // override
```

Blog post: [Possibility to generate arbitrary class implementations in macros](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2022/06/21/scala-3.1.3-released.html#possibility-to-generate-arbitrary-class-implementations-in-macros)

Scaladoc: [Symbol.newClass](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.1.3/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L3601-L3642)

Issue: [Support creating a new instance of a given Type[A] with Scala 3 macro](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/153)

How to access constructor:

- [How to create an instance of a generic type in a Scala 3 macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738828/how-to-create-an-instance-of-a-generic-type-in-a-scala-3-macro)
- [How to access parameter list of case class in a dotty macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853337/how-to-access-parameter-list-of-case-class-in-a-dotty-macro)
- [How do I use macro to create objects of any class](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/discussions/12590)
  (`Apply(Select.unique(New(TypeTree.of[T]), "<init>")...`)

[Scala 2 Append A Method To Class Body (Metaprogramming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656261/scala-2-append-a-method-to-class-body-metaprogramming) (Scala 2, compiler plugin)

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/16128