# How to splice multiple expressions in quote syntax of scala 3 macros?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I learned how to splice expr in quotes now. But I didn't find how to splice multiple exprs in a quote.
I have a selectable trait and a macro impl function:

```scala
trait StructuralTypeRoot extends Selectable

def macroImpl(using q: Quotes): Expr[Any] = {
  val exprs: Vector[Expr[Any]] = Vector(
    '{def f = 1},
    '{def g = 2}) /*make some method def exprs here*/

  '{
    new StructuralTypeRoot{
      ${exprs} // can't do this. How can i splice exprs here
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess it makes sense that you can't just splice a `Seq` (or `Vector`) of `Expr`s. You might have to do some lower-level stuff with the `Quotes` instance.

Comment: If each expression is independent, a way to do that could be combined expression with `;`.
For example, you can write:
`val combinedExpression : Expr[Any] = exprs.reduce((a, b) => '{$a;$b})`
In this way, `combinedExpression` is an Expr[Any] (not a `Vector`).
BTW I don't know if it is possible to do what you want with splicing, namely adding method to an anonymous object.

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi this will generate a block. If place it in a class body, it actually in constructor instead of definitions of class.

Comment: I see... What you want to do with `new StructuralTypeRoot { ${expr} }`? Have you already tried with a single expression??

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi  I don't know how to splice it. So the code in question is just my intention:  dynamically create a set of methods from a list in a class or trait body

Comment: Have you read this [article](https://softwaremill.com/scala-3-macros-tips-and-tricks/#:~:text=Scala%203%20offers%20two%20basic%20metaprogramming%20modes%3A%20inlines,inline%20summon%20%28looking%20up%20given%20%2F%20implicit%20values%29.)? I think that to do the "dynamical" method injection you should leverage also `qouted.reflect.*`.

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi Yes, It's a way to manipulate Trees, but not friendly enough. Thanks for your answer. I'll try to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros