# How to extract all methods in scala 3 using a tasty inspector?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, tasty

I am trying to use a tasty inspector to convert method params to case classes but I get a classcast exception at runtime.

My code:

```scala
import dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.{PackageDef, Template}

import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*

class MyInspector extends Inspector:
  def inspect(using Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit =
    for tasty <- tastys do
      import tasty.quotes.reflect.*
      tasty.ast match {
        case PackageDef(pid, stats) =>
          stats.collect { case TypeDef(typeName, Template(constr, parentsOrDerived, self, preBody: List[_])) =>
            preBody.collect { case DefDef(name, paramss: List[List[_]] @unchecked, tpt, preRhs) =>
              val params = paramss.flatten.map { case ValDef(name, tpt, preRhs) =>
                s"$name : ${tpt.show}"
              }
              println(s"""
                   |case class ${typeName}_${name}_ccIn(${params.mkString(", ")})
                   |""".stripMargin)
              println("------------------------")
            }
          }
      }

@main def tryit() =
  val tastyFiles = List("../example-commands/classpath-1/target/scala-3.2.1/classes/cp1/Cp1Exports.tasty")
  TastyInspector.inspectTastyFiles(tastyFiles)(new MyInspector)
```

I run this against this class (after I compile it and the compiler creates a .tasty file):

```scala
package cp1

import java.time.LocalDate

trait Cp1Exports:
  def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int
  def subtract(a: Int, b: Int): Int
  def friends(p: Person, from: LocalDate): Seq[Person]

case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
```

But I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees$Import cannot be cast to class dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees$TypeDef (dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees$Import and dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees$TypeDef are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$TypeDef$.unapply(QuotesImpl.scala:339)
    at console.macros.MyInspector$$anon$1.applyOrElse(MyInspector.scala:15)
```

The line causing the issue is this:

```scala
          stats.collect { case TypeDef(typeName, Template(constr, parentsOrDerived, self, preBody: List[_])) =>
```

But it shouldn't because this is a collect. The error is caused because there is an import in Cp1Exports. If I remove the import, it works.

Also any advice to simplify the code would be appreciated.

I am using scala 3.2.1 (incl scala-compiler with that version)

EDIT:

Ok after following the advice from below, I ended up with this code which works (but seems rather complicated):

```scala
import dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.*

import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*

class MyInspector extends Inspector:
  def inspect(using Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit =
    for tasty <- tastys do
      given dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context = scala.quoted.quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx
      tasty.ast match {
        case PackageDef(pid, stats) =>
          stats.collect { case TypeDef(typeName, Template(constr, parentsOrDerived, self, preBody: List[_])) =>
            preBody.collect { case DefDef(name, paramss: List[List[_]] @unchecked, tpt, preRhs) =>
              val params = paramss.flatten.map { case ValDef(name, tpt, preRhs) =>
                s"$name : ${tpt.show}"
              }
              println(s"""
                   |case class ${typeName}_${name}_ccIn(${params.mkString(", ")})
                   |""".stripMargin)
              println("------------------------")
            }
          }
      }

@main def tryit() =
  val tastyFiles = List("../example-commands/classpath-1/target/scala-3.2.1/classes/cp1/Cp1Exports.tasty")
  TastyInspector.inspectTastyFiles(tastyFiles)(new MyInspector)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried working with `Symbol`s rather than `Tree`s? They are much better abstraction to query about things. See API at https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/0397de1bba206e4b41e9ba2be4bcd0d418ca05d4/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L3560

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok how do I get a Symbol out of "tasty" in my example above? I don't see any method (and intellij isn't much of help, both me and intellij can't make heads or tails out of it). I also can't find a lot of documentation online. Thanks

Comment: `tasty.ast` is a `Tree` right? It should have `.symbol` method: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/0397de1bba206e4b41e9ba2be4bcd0d418ca05d4/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L278 . IntelliJ doesn't understand macros, but it sometimes helps if you use `using quotes: Quote` and then `import quotes.*` (you haven't done it so you don't have the extension methods and objects in scope). If intellisense isn't working having `Quotes.tasty` opened in a tab is quite helpful (double shift to search outside project files, then type `Quotes` into search bar).

Comment: Thanks @MateuszKubuszok . I am trying it but I couldn't make much progress. I read tasty.ast.symbol, cast it as dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols.Symbol (this is the type I get at runtime) but then every method is "using" Context, how do I get that context? (sorry again intellij is useless and without autocomplete or been able to open types I am blind). But even with context available I don't see which method to call to examine the types defined in the file.

Comment: @kostas.kougios *"how do I get that context?"* `given dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context = scala.quoted.quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx` See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549477/scala3-crafting-types-through-metaprogramming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that

```
stats.collect { case dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.TypeDef(_, _) => }
```

doesn't throw while

```
stats.collect { TypeDef(_, _) => }
```

aka

```
stats.collect { tasty.quotes.reflect.TypeDef(_, _) => }
```

does.

The difference seems to be that `dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.TypeDef` is a case class while `tasty.quotes.reflect.TypeDef` is an abstract type.

The reason seems to be type erasure

[Understanding why inlining function fixes runtime crash when collecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880462/understanding-why-inlining-function-fixes-runtime-crash-when-collecting)

Simpler reproduction:

```
import scala.reflect.TypeTest

trait X {
  type A

  type B <: A
  trait BModule {
    def unapply(b: B): Option[Int]
  }
  val B: BModule
  given BTypeTest: TypeTest[A, B]

  type C <: A
  trait CModule {
    def unapply(c: C): Option[String]
  }
  val C: CModule
  given CTypeTest: TypeTest[A, C]
}

object XImpl extends X {
  sealed trait A

  case class B(i: Int) extends A
  object B extends BModule {
    def unapply(b: B): Option[Int] = Some(b.i)
  }
  object BTypeTest extends TypeTest[A, B] {
    override def unapply(x: A): Option[x.type & B] = x match {
      case x: (B & x.type) => Some(x)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  case class C(s: String) extends A
  object C extends CModule {
    def unapply(c: C): Option[String] = Some(c.s)
  }
  object CTypeTest extends TypeTest[A, C] {
    override def unapply(x: A): Option[x.type & C] = x match {
      case x: (C & x.type) => Some(x)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}

def foo()(using x: X) = {
  import x.*

  List(XImpl.B(1), XImpl.C("a")).collect { case C(s) => println(s) }
}

given X = XImpl

foo() // ClassCastException: XImpl$B cannot be cast to XImpl$C
```

Here `X`, `A`, `B`, `C` are similar to `Quotes`, `Tree`, `ValDef`, `TypeDef`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an "Edit" section in my question with the code as is after applying your comments. It still seems a bit complicated to me, is there a way to simplify the pattern matches and the "given"?

Comment: I believe the issues with type erasure are non existent when you do it as documentation says and import `import quotes.*` and `import quotes.reflect.*`. Why? Because these imports besides: types, their companions amd extension methods also import `TypeTest` which are used in pattern matching to counter type erasure. While IDE isn't helpful right now, a lot of issues with both question and this answer comes from not importing everything documentation tells you to import.

Answer (score 0):

Casting and inspecting runtime types of Quotes is over-complicating. I understand that it comes from poor IDE support, so I'll explain how to avoid it.

Then you import you project into IntelliJ, it will not handle path-dependent types well, and macros - both in Scala 2 and in Scala 3 - rely on them, so the IDE support is poor. However, in Scala 3 you can learn how to work around it.

You are starting with this:

```
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*
```

These imports will allow you to create the `Inspector` instance:

```
class PrintInspector extends Inspector {

  override def inspect(using quotes: Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit = ???
}
```

Pay attention to the fact that `Quotes` `using` is named and we are referring to it in second argument list. It allow us to express that for each `tasty: Tasty[quotes.type]` value:

- `tasty.ast` will be of type `quotes.reflect.Tree`
- `tasty.quote` is the same type as `quote` (so we might import the latter everywhere)

To work with `Quotes` and `reflect` you should do 2 wildcard imports:

```
// same type as content of each Tasty[quotes.type].quotes
import quotes.*
import quotes.reflect.*
```

Here IDE support will start getting poor:

- when you open [`Quotes`](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/0397de1bba206e4b41e9ba2be4bcd0d418ca05d4/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L278) in your IDE you will see all the companion objects and extension methods that you should be able to access
- however IntelliJ (in my case, at the moment I am writing this) only recognizes imported types, while fails to recognize extension methods and companion object methods
- so I am helping myself annotating types rather than relying on what is inferred to have better IDE experience

How do I work with it? An example:

```
  tastys.foreach { tasty =>
    val path = tasty.path
    val tree: Tree = tasty.ast
    val symbol: Symbol = tree.symbol
  }
```

I saw in `Tasty`'s source code that I should have access to `tasty.ast` method and that is should be `Tree` (imported from `quotes.reflect.*`). IntelliJ will assume it's `Any` so I will annotate it myself.

Similarly I can see in `Quotes` source code that `Tree` has `.symbol` extension method.

This way I am avoiding the madness in which I am casting things to internal compiler types and figuring our implicits to pass that were never intended for API user to pass manually. (And opening `Quotes.tasty`, `Inspector.tasty`, `Tasty.tasty` etc to preview methods can be done in IntelliJ with double shift, typing the name and then double shift again to search in dependencies. Once opened I keep e.g. `Quotes.tasty` on the right side of the screen and a file which use the API on the left side).

Once we are working with sane-but-not-intellisense supported API we can write this:

```
//> using scala "3.2.1"
//> using lib "org.scala-lang::scala3-tasty-inspector:3.2.1"

import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*

class PrintInspector extends Inspector {

  override def inspect(using quotes: Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit = {
    // same type as content of each Tasty[quotes.type].quotes
    import quotes.*
    import quotes.reflect.*

    def processSymbol(sym: Symbol): Vector[String] = {
      if (sym == Symbol.noSymbol) {
        Vector.empty
      } else if (sym.isPackageDef) {
        // it's a package
        val name: String = s"package ${sym.name}"
        val decl: List[Symbol] = sym.declarations
        name +: decl.view.flatMap(processSymbol).map("  " + _).toVector
      } else if (sym.isClassDef) {
        // it's a class
        val name: String = s"class ${sym.name}"
        val decl: List[Symbol] = sym.declarations
        name +: decl.view.flatMap(processSymbol).map("  " + _).toVector
      } else if (sym.isDefDef) {
        // it's a def (not val)
        val name: String = s"def ${sym.name}"
        val decl: List[Symbol] = sym.paramSymss.flatten // parameter lists of this method
        name +: decl.view.flatMap(processSymbol).map("  " + _).toVector
      } else if (sym.isValDef) {
        // it's a val
        val name: String = s"val ${sym.name}"
        Vector(name)
      } else if (sym.isType) {
        // it's type
        val name: String = s"type ${sym.name}"
        Vector(name)
      } else {
        // it's another symbol (binding, etd)
        Vector.empty
      }
    }

    tastys.foreach { tasty =>
      val path = tasty.path
      val tree: Tree = tasty.ast
      val symbol: Symbol = tree.symbol
      val result = processSymbol(symbol)

      println("-------------------------------")
      println(path)
      println()
      result.foreach(println)
    }
  }
}
object PrintInspector {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    TastyInspector.inspectTastyFiles(args.toList)(new PrintInspector)
  }
}
```

I wrote this quickly as a demo of the IDEa how to traverse Tasty using symbols API. When I compiled it with `scala-cli` and run against it's own tasty I got

```
# create Tasty files somewhere
> scala-cli compile .
Compiling project (Scala 3.2.1, JVM)
Compiled project (Scala 3.2.1, JVM)
# pass Tasty files from previpus compilation into the script to print itself
> scala-cli run PrintInspector.scala -- .scala-build/project_eb4be2fafa/classes/main/PrintInspector.tasty                                                                                     
Compiling project (Scala 3.2.1, JVM)
Compiled project (Scala 3.2.1, JVM)
-------------------------------
.scala-build/project_eb4be2fafa/classes/main/PrintInspector.class

package <empty>
  class PrintInspector
    def <init>
    def inspect
      val quotes
      val tastys
  val PrintInspector
  class PrintInspector$
    def <init>
    def writeReplace
    def main
      val args
    def apply
```

I believe this would be relatively easy for you to adapt to use extracted information to print `case classes` for each method or whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks once again @mateusz , I run the code against my Cp1Exports and I got an exception, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: complete . Maybe an impl is missing for classes. This throws the exception:

```
  trait NoCompleter extends LazyType {
    def complete(denot: SymDenotation)(using Context): Unit = unsupported("complete")
  }
```

Also intellij is still helpless on mine, i.e. it can't autocomplete tree.symbol (it can't figure out there is a symbol method) even if tree is declared as Tree

Comment: 1. As I say: IntelliJ does NOT help with path dependent types. If you need them (and you do need them fro Quotes and friends) you just need to learn without autocomplete from IntelliJ. You open 2 windows, 1 for `Quotes.tasty`, 1 for file which uses it, and you write your code as if it was Sublime Text with only syntax highlighting installed. 2. I am not sure what you did but there was no `???` in my code, so try to modify thing 1 step at a time, recompile and rerun with 1 change at a time.

Comment: Hi Mateusz, no the ??? is not in your code, it is in the scala lib code. Your code runs as is but when I point it to my Cp1Exports.tasty file it fails.