# Macro class name expansion in Scala 3

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

I am trying to use the macros with quoted DSL for generating a class like this  —

```scala
val name = ???

'{
  final class ${name} {
    def foo: String = ...
    def bar: Int = ...
  }
}
```

The idea is to generate a class with a particular `name`. If `name` is of type `String` then the scala compiler throws syntax error. Same is true for `Expr`.

What should be the type of name? Expr doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a quote you can create only a class with statically known name (the code inside a quote must typecheck). If the name of a class is a string you should go deeper and use [reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/reflection.html) API

[Method Override with Scala 3 Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros)

Please notice that the class will be generated inside a block (Scala 3 macros are def macros), so will be visible only there.