# `tq` equivalent in Scala 3 macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, scala-quasiquotes

With Scala2 I could implement a macro and generate types using `tq` quasiquote syntax, for eg:

```scala
q"""        
new Foo {
  type Bar = ${tq"(..$params)"}
}
"""
```

I am able to do two things with this syntax  -

1. Able to define a type `Bar` based on the `params`.
2. Able to spread the `params` as a tuple.

How can I achieve this with Scala 3?

Comment: Depending on where you get `params` from you might be able to use match types.

Answer (score 5):

There are no [quasiquotes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html) (`q"..."`, `tq"..."`, `pq"..."`, `cq"..."`, `fq"..."`) in Scala 3. Feel yourself like in early days of macros in Scala 2.10 :)

Scala 3 [quotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html) `'{...}` (and splicing `${...}`) must  typecheck not only at compile time of the main code (i.e. runtime of macros, the time when macros expand) but also earlier at compile time of macros themselves. This is [similar](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-reify) to `reify {...}` (and `.splice`) in Scala 2.

`new Foo {...}` is actually an instance of an anonymous class extending `Foo`. So see your previous question [Macro class name expansion in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848992/macro-class-name-expansion-in-scala-3), [Method Override with Scala 3 Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros)

Everything depends on whether `Foo` and `params` are known statically. If so then everything is easy:

```scala
import scala.quoted.*

trait Foo

inline def doSmth[A](x: Int): Unit = ${doSmthImpl[A]('x)}

def doSmthImpl[A](x: Expr[Int])(using Quotes, Type[A]): Expr[Unit]= {
//    import quotes.reflect.*

  '{

    new Foo {
      type Bar = (Double, Boolean)
    }

    
    // doing smth with this instance
  }
}
```

or

```scala
val params = Type.of[(Double, Boolean)]

'{
  new Foo {
    type Bar = $params
  }
}
```

or

```scala
'{
  new Foo {
    type Bar = params.Underlying
  }
}
```

In comments **@Jasper-M** advises how to handle the case when we have `Foo` statically but `params` not statically:

```scala
type X

given Type[X] = paramsTypeTree.tpe.asType.asInstanceOf[Type[X]]

'{
  new Foo {
    type Bar = X
  }
}
```

or

```scala
paramsTypeTree.tpe.asType match {
  case '[x] =>
    '{
      new Foo {
        type Bar = x
      }
    }
}
```

Now suppose that `Foo` is not known statically. Since there are no quasiquotes the only different way of constructing trees in Scala 3 is to go deeper to Tasty [reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/reflection.html) level and build a tree manually. So you can print a tree of statically typechecked code and try to reconstruct it manually. The code

```scala
println('{
  new Foo {
    type Bar = (Double, Boolean)
  }
}.asTerm.underlyingArgument.show
```

prints

```scala
{
  final class $anon() extends App.Foo {
    type Bar = scala.Tuple2[scala.Double, scala.Boolean]
  }

  (new $anon(): App.Foo)
}
```

And

```scala
println('{
  new Foo {
     type Bar = (Double, Boolean)
  }
}.asTerm.underlyingArgument.show(using Printer.TreeStructure))
```

prints

```scala
Block(
  List(ClassDef(
    "$anon",
    DefDef("<init>", List(TermParamClause(Nil)), Inferred(), None),
    List(
      Apply(Select(New(Inferred()), "<init>"), Nil),
      TypeIdent("Foo")
    ),
    None,
    List(TypeDef(
      "Bar",
      Applied(
        Inferred(),
        List(TypeIdent("Double"), TypeIdent("Boolean")) // this should be params
      )
    ))
  )),
  Typed(
    Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent("$anon")), "<init>"), Nil),
    Inferred()
  )
)
```

One more complication here is that Scala 3 macros accept typed trees and must return typed trees. So we must handle symbols as well.

Actually, in reflection API I [can see](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.0/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L3600-L3703) `Symbol.newMethod`, `Symbol.newClass`, `Symbol.newVal`, `Symbol.newBind` but no `Symbol.newType`. (It turns out a method for new type member is not exposed to the reflection API, so we have to use [internal](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.0/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/core/Symbols.scala#L514-L527) `dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols.newSymbol`.)

I can imagine something like

```scala
val fooTypeTree = TypeTree.ref(Symbol.classSymbol("mypackage.App.Foo"))
val parents = List(TypeTree.of[AnyRef], fooTypeTree)

def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] = {
  given dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context = 
    quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx
  import dotty.tools.dotc.core.Decorators.toTypeName
  List(dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols.newSymbol(
    cls.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols.Symbol],
    "Bar".toTypeName,
    Flags.EmptyFlags/*Override*/.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.core.Flags.FlagSet],
    TypeRepr.of[(Double, Boolean)]/*params*/.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types.Type]
  ).asInstanceOf[Symbol])
}

val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner, "FooImpl", parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
val typeSym = cls.declaredType("Bar").head

val typeDef = TypeDef(typeSym)
val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(typeDef))
val newCls = Typed(Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent(cls)), cls.primaryConstructor), Nil), fooTypeTree)

Block(List(clsDef, newCls), '{()}.asTerm).asExprOf[Unit]

//{
//  class FooImpl extends java.lang.Object with mypackage.App.Foo {
//    type Bar = scala.Tuple2[scala.Double, scala.Boolean]
//  }
//
//  (new FooImpl(): mypackage.App.Foo)
//  ()
//}

package mypackage

object App {
 trait Foo
}
```

Scala 3 macros are *def* macros, all generated definitions will be seen only inside the block that a macro expands into.

Maybe if it's enough to generate code at pre-compile time you can consider to use [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/). There are quasiquotes there :) `q"..."`, `t"..."`, `p"..."`, `param"..."`, `tparam"..."`,  `init"..."`, `self"..."`, `template"..."`, `mod"..."`, `enumerator"..."`, `import"..."`, `importer"..."`, `importee"..."`, `source"..."`.

Comment: You might be able to hack something together with `type X; given Type[X] = arbitraryTypeTree.tpe.asType.asInstanceOf; '{ new Foo { type Bar = X } }`

Comment: Ah, you can get the same effect as my previous comment with `arbitraryTypeTree.tpe.asType match { case '[x] => ... }`. Makes me wonder why you have to go through these hoops instead of being able to just splice a `Type` instance directly.

Comment: @Jasper-M Great. Thanks. Yeah, I was talking about the case when we don't have `Foo` statically.

Comment: Yeah if you don't have `Foo` you indeed have to create the whole tree manually.

Comment: @Jasper-M Yeah and my understanding is that currently there is no api for creating/overriding type member. Only class, method or val.