# Scala 3 macros: create a new polynmorphic function using the reflect api

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros, scala-3, scala-quasiquotes

I intend to create the simple polymorphic function expression below using the `Quotes.reflect` API:

```
new PolyFunction {
  def apply[X](a: X): X = a
}
```

What I have attempted is shown below with parts that I could not implement replaced by `???`:

```
val name: String = "$anon"
val parents = List(TypeTree.of[Object], TypeTree.of[PolyFunction])
def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
  List(
    Symbol.newMethod(
      cls,
      "apply",
      MethodType(List("a"))(
        { mt =>
          ???
        },
        mt => ???
      )
    )
  )
val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner, name, parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
val applySym = cls.declaredMethod("apply").head

val applyDef = DefDef(applySym, argss => Some(???))
val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(applyDef))
val closure = Block(List(clsDef),Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent(cls)), cls.primaryConstructor), Nil))
closure.asExpr
```

The problem, mainly, is I am unable to declare the type parameter `X`, and its reference in the first value parameter and the functions return type. I have noticed some reflection functions are annotated as `experimental`.

Comment: Why do you need reflection low-level api? Why can't you use quotation `def myMacroImpl(using Quotes): Expr[PolyFunction] = '{ new PolyFunction { def apply[X](a: X): X = a } }`? Because this is just an example and your actual use case is more complicated, yeah?

Comment: @DmytroMitin This is a proof of concept only example, In practice, my aim is to create a wrapper around every polymorphic function that I receive as input with an arbitrary number of type and value parameters, with the same type signature, and quote patterns are not good at matching  arbitrary inputs. (or are they?...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `PolyType` along with `MethodType`

```scala
import scala.annotation.experimental
import scala.quoted.*

inline def newPoly: PolyFunction = ${newPolyImpl}

@experimental
def newPolyImpl(using Quotes): Expr[PolyFunction] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val name: String = "$anon"
  val parents = List(TypeTree.of[Object], TypeTree.of[PolyFunction])

  def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
    List(
      Symbol.newMethod(
        cls,
        "apply",
        PolyType(List("X"))(_ => List(TypeBounds.empty), polyType => {
          val typeParam = polyType.param(0)
          MethodType(List("a"))(_ => List(typeParam), _ => typeParam)
        })
      )
    )

  val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner, name, parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
  val applySym = cls.declaredMethod("apply").head

  // argss=List(List(TypeTree[TypeRef(NoPrefix,type X)]), List(Ident(a)))
  val applyDef = DefDef(applySym, argss => Some(argss(1)(0).asInstanceOf[Term]))
  val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(applyDef))
  val closure = Block(List(clsDef), Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent(cls)), cls.primaryConstructor), Nil))
  closure.asExprOf[PolyFunction]
}
```

Usage:

```scala
newPoly

//scalac: {
//  class $anon extends java.lang.Object with scala.PolyFunction {
//    def apply[X](a: X): X = a
//  }
//  new $anon()
//}
```

Scala 3.2.1

[Method Override with Scala 3 Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros)

[Scala3: Crafting Types Through Metaprogramming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549477/scala3-crafting-types-through-metaprogramming)

[`tq` equivalent in Scala 3 macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852787/tq-equivalent-in-scala-3-macros)

Comment: Any idea how to create the PolyType for hkt `X[_]`?