# Add annotation to a method defined using a Symbol.newMethod

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

Type `scala.quoted.Quotes.reflectModule.SymbolMethods` has a method called `annotations` which returns annotations attached to the input symbol.

Type `scala.quoted.Quotes.reflectModule.SymbolModule` has two methods called `newMethod` that generate "a new method symbol with the given parent, name and type."

How can I attach annotations to the methods I create with `newMethod`.
In particular, I am interested in adding `@targetName` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Current `Quotes` API is not perfect. To add annotation try compiler internals

```
extension (symb: Symbol)
  def addAnnotation(annotation: Term): Symbol =
    // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value %% "scala3-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
    given dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context =
      quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx
    symb.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols.Symbol]
      .denot
      .addAnnotation(
        dotty.tools.dotc.core.Annotations.ConcreteAnnotation(
          annotation.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.ast.tpd.Tree]
        )
      )
    symb

Symbol.newMethod(...)
  .addAnnotation('{new scala.annotation.targetName("foo")}.asTerm)
```

For example

```
import scala.annotation.experimental
import scala.quoted.*

inline def newClass[A]: A = ${newClassImpl[A]}

@experimental
def newClassImpl[A: Type](using Quotes): Expr[A] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  extension (symb: Symbol)
    def addAnnotation(annotation: Term): Symbol = ...

  val name: String = TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol.name + "Impl"
  val parents = List(TypeTree.of[A])

  def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
    List(
      Symbol.newMethod(cls, "func", MethodType(List("s"))(_ => List(TypeRepr.of[String]), _ => TypeRepr.of[String]), Flags.Override, Symbol.noSymbol)
        .addAnnotation('{new scala.annotation.targetName("foo")}.asTerm)
    )

  val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner, name, parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
  val funcSym = cls.declaredMethod("func").head

  val funcDef = DefDef(funcSym, argss => Some('{ "override" }.asTerm))
  val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(funcDef))
  val newCls = Typed(Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent(cls)), cls.primaryConstructor), Nil), TypeTree.of[A])

  Block(List(clsDef), newCls).asExprOf[A]
```

```
class TestClass:
  def func(s: String) = "base"

val res: TestClass = newClass[TestClass]

   // scalacOptions += "-Xprint:pickleQuotes"
// {
//   class TestClassImpl extends TestClass {
//     @targetName override def func(s: String): String = "override"
//   }
//   new TestClassImpl():TestClass
// }:TestClass
```

[Scala 3 macros: create a new polynmorphic function using the reflect api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141523/scala-3-macros-create-a-new-polynmorphic-function-using-the-reflect-api)

[Method Override with Scala 3 Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros)

[`tq` equivalent in Scala 3 macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852787/tq-equivalent-in-scala-3-macros)

[Scala3: Crafting Types Through Metaprogramming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549477/scala3-crafting-types-through-metaprogramming)

Not sure whether this `@targetName` works [as expected](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/targetName.html).

Also we can define

```
extension (symb: Symbol)
  def addTargetName(name: String): Symbol =
    given dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context =
      quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx
    import dotty.tools.dotc.core.Decorators.toTermName
    symb.asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.core.Symbols.Symbol]
      .denot
      .setTargetName(name.toTermName)
    symb
```

It's possible that `@targetName` is handled before [macros are expanded](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.2/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/Compiler.scala#L48-L55). In such case it's too late to add it with macros.